# How to delete an empty table from dataframe python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that contains multiple empty tables. This dataframe is read from a csv file. Is there a way to delete empty tables from a dataframe using pandas?

**Note:** it's not empty rows, the tables have no rows. The table is completely empty. I attached a picture for reference.

For this example, the first table has two columns: `product_name_tmall` and `product_price_tmall`, but it has no values. The second table has two columns with the same names and it has values. I want to delete the first table.
[image]

Comment: what do you mean by table?

Comment: Could you add a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: So by table, I meant above line thirty, there is an empty table. It has two columns: product_name_tmall and product_price_tmall, and this table has no value. I want to delete this table.

Comment: hi, I don't really understand what you are meaning when you say that the dataframe presents an empty table inside it. As far as I understood, what you are calling table is actually just a row that presents the same information of the header. Is it?

Answer (score 0):

You can test if all values not matched columns names by [`DataFrame.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ne.html) and [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) and then filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[df.ne(df.columns).all(axis=1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I add my edits below the previous answer.

y̶o̶u̶ ̶c̶a̶n̶ ̶t̶r̶y̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶d̶r̶o̶p̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶m̶,̶ ̶i̶f̶ ̶y̶o̶u̶ ̶k̶n̶o̶w̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶i̶r̶ ̶i̶n̶d̶e̶x̶.̶ ̶I̶f̶ ̶I̶ ̶g̶o̶t̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶m̶ ̶f̶r̶o̶m̶ ̶y̶o̶u̶r̶ ̶e̶x̶e̶m̶p̶l̶e̶,̶ ̶c̶o̶u̶l̶d̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶y̶ ̶b̶e̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶2̶9̶t̶h̶-̶3̶0̶t̶h̶?̶

```
d̶f̶.̶d̶r̶o̶p̶(̶[̶2̶9̶,̶ ̶3̶0̶]̶,̶ ̶i̶n̶p̶l̶a̶c̶e̶=̶T̶r̶u̶e̶)
```

Can you try to identify which rows are presenting what you're calling an "empty table" and try to filter them out?
What about something like this?

```
df[(df!='product_name_tmall')&(df!='product_price_tmall')].dropna(how='all')
```

Comment: I can't really do that. I have lots of csv files and each of them have empty tables at different places. I'm looking for a way to delete the empty tables automatically for CSV